# Can a septic effluent filter be installed on a pumped system?

Tags: septic, filter

I have found only 4"+ and larger septic effluent filters, and they all are not rated for pressure or the flow rates of a pumped system. This leads me to believe that there are not effluent filters available for pumped systems, which are typically 2" like mine. Is this correct? Or am I missing something else obvious?

Comment: Position in the system, perhaps. Most pumped systems pump to somewhere that gravity takes over for settling, flotation & distribution to the drain field. The interface between that and the drain field would be where to put one. Others have settliong, flotation, and a pump to dose the drain field - in that case the location would be before the pump reservior, after the settling & flotation. Consult with your sanitary engineer to determine where, if anywhere, is appropriate in the particular system you have (there are many variations.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Unfortunately this is pumped to a d-box, which then has many outlets to the field. There's no one point of gravity distribution that has a single outlet.